# Non-parametric test of 3 samples

Tags: nonparametric

My classmate is working on a scientific investigatory project entitled ANTIMICROBIAL ACTIVITY OF UBE Discorea alata L. LEAVES PURE EXTRACT ETHANOLIC EXTRACT IN INHIBITING THE GROWTH OF Klebsiella pneumoniae and we want to know what statistical treatment will fit on her study.

She wants to compare the antimicrobial activity of ube extracts and a commercial product of the same purpose. She measured the performance of her variable, that is ube extracts,  in 3 trials and found out the following data 19, 19, 20 mm clearing zone.

While the commercial product is 38 mm clearing zone in 3 trials. Normality of data does not hold here and we suspect non parametric test but we are not certain of what test might compare if there is a significant difference between the mean of the two products; the ube extracts and the commercial product.

Comment: Could you explain how you know or why you assume "normality of data does not hold here"?  This is important, because no standard nonparametric test will determine there is a difference, yet there seems to be a strikingly large one.  Thus, the success of your statistical treatment must rely on the assumptions you make.

Comment: I used the normality test here sir and i found out that normality of tbe data does not hold in these example...at first i want to use independent t test but that is only applicable for approximately normal distribution with considerable large sample size, but based on my example i had only 3 pairs of data... thats why i think this seek for a non parametric test but i dunno what exact non parametric test should i rely on.

Comment: Although you don't say which normality test you used, I doubt that any such test (if correctly applied) could have any chance of rejecting the hypothesis of normality.  You don't have enough data to test for normality: *you have to have additional information* to support any distributional assumption, such as previous knowledge of how the results in each group are likely to vary.  If your standard for significance is any stronger than 10%, then don't bother to apply a nonparametric test: none of them can give a p-value less than 10% for these data.

Comment: Please guide me with this one sir, what should I do?